# Basic Authentication in front of CKAN - too many redirects

Tags: basic-authentication, ckan

I'm currently setting up a ckan and it was asked that before anyone could access the website, basic authentication was done. After that the user can check out the CKAN without a problem. However my problem resides in the fact that the basic authentication, before anything of CKAN is shown, somehow interferes with CKAN's log-in system. If I, after I entered my BA credentials, want to log in it returns me a "too many redirects". Ofcourse when I don't include basic authentication in my virtualhost, the log-in of ckan works without a problem.

So my question is two-sided, is there a way to let CKAN know that the basic authentication used isn't something he should be using and apparently see as a CKAN user.

Or is there a module in CKAN that allows for Basic Authentication to be asked before anything is shown on the website at all.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!

Found my solution by asking it the ckan mailing list. Altering your apache.wsgi running in your ckan should do the trick. Take a look at [this file](https://github.com/okfn/ckanext-geodatagov/blob/master/deployment/etc/ckan/apache.wsgi#L13) and add line 13 14 15 17 to your apache.wsgi file and you should be fine. At least I stopped getting endless redirects and was able to log-in after I filled in my Basic Authentication. This however implies that when you use the CKAN API you'll need to use X-CKAN-API-Key header or specify another header in the config file.